# Write contiguous structured data to a binary file using C#

Tags: c#, c, memory-management, struct, binary

I am doing a project in which I need to write structured data into a binary file. First I need to write a header, then fetch data from somewhere, populate and write the structured data blocks to the said file.  I am porting C structs to C# as follows:

C header struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    DWORD uSignature;       
    DWORD uRecordLength;    
} Header;
```

C data struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    DWORD uCode;   // a two character identifier            
    char uLabel[10];
    int uDate;
    float uData[37];               
} MyData;
```

Here is the C# header struct:

```
    struct Header
    {
        public uint uSignature;       
        public uint uRecordLength;    
    }
```

and here is the C# data struct:

```
    struct MyData
    {
        public MyData (int Count) : this ()
        {
            uData = new Single[Count];
        }
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
        public byte[] uCode;               
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
        public byte[] uLabel;   
        public int uDate;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 37)]
        public Single [] uData;     
    }
```

This file will be read by another application which can read from the binary file if data correctly formatted. I printed out the size of the two struct types and they look good. However, the output file can not be read by the said application.

So I have two questions:

1. Are the data types and Marshals I used correctly in C to C# conversion?
2. I use FileStream and BinaryWriter to write to the binary file. All data (header and subsequent data) must be in sequence (contiguous) . As I create and write data structs on the fly, I am not sure how to allocate continuous memory using something like:

```
public static byte[] GetData(object obj)
{

    var size = Marshal.SizeOf(obj.GetType());            
    var data = new byte[size];            
    IntPtr pnt = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

        try
        {
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, pnt, true);
            // Copy the array to unmanaged memory.
            Marshal.Copy(pnt, data, 0, size);
            return data;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Free the unmanaged memory.
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pnt);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[EDIT]
I added two methods to convert specific struct data into byte array, but the file is still unreadable:

```
   private byte[] DataToByteArray(MyData data)
    {
        int len = 0;
        var size = Marshal.SizeOf(data.GetType());
        var barray = new byte[size];
        data.uCode.CopyTo(barray, 0);
        len += data.uCode.Length;
        data.uLabel.CopyTo(barray, len);
        len += data.uLabel.Length;
        BitConverter.GetBytes(0).CopyTo(barray, len);
        len += data.uData.Length;
        Buffer.BlockCopy(data.uData, 0, barray, len, data.uData.Length);

        return barray;
    }

    private byte[] HeadToByteArray(Header data)
    {
        var size = Marshal.SizeOf(data.GetType());
        var barray = new byte[size];
        BitConverter.GetBytes(data.uSignature).CopyTo(barray, 0);
        BitConverter.GetBytes(data.uRecordLength).CopyTo(barray, 4);

        return barray;
    }
```

【EDIT2】
Here is how it works in C:

```
#define     NQ_EX            'QN'
FILE *fout;
fopen_s(&fout, "path_to_the_file", "wb");
Header head = { val1, sizeof(MyData) };
fwrite(&head, sizeof(Header), 1, fout);

while (!stop && data_is_coming)
{
    MyData data;
    memset(&data, 0, sizeof(data));
    data.uCode = NQ_EX;
    sprintf_s(data.uLabel, "%s", getVal("field1"));
    data.uData[0] = getVal("field2");
    data.uData[1] = getVal("field3");
    ....
    fwrite(&data, sizeof(MyData), 1, fout);
}
```

Comment: You're writing C#, not C. If you don't need to interface directly with C code running in the same process, you generally don't want to bother with marshaling, because now you have two problems (understanding what C does, and translating this into C# somehow). If you use sequential calls of `BitConverter.GetBytes()`, you only have one problem (understanding what C does), and that reduces to alignment, endianness and the way C handles strings (with '\0' termination).

Comment: Maybe forcing the layout is what you're missing? i.e.

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        struct MyData
        {
            public MyData(int Count)
                : this()
            {
                uData = new Single[Count];
            }

            [FieldOffset(0)]
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
            public byte[] uCode;

            [FieldOffset(4)]
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
            public byte[] uLabel;
 etc ...

Comment: It is difficult to overstate the importance and usefulness of the advice provided in the comment from @Jeroen. There really is little or no justification for trying to go through the p/invoke layer just to read and write binary data from a stream. .NET has usable classes, like `BinaryReader`, `BinaryWriter`, and `BitConverter` to deal with this kind of scenario. They are easier to use, and produce reliable results. Frankly, even in C/C++ it's a bad idea to use in-memory layout for serialization; too fragile, much better to serialize explicitly. Don't make the mistake of keeping the habit in C#

Comment: @JeroenMostert, If I understood you, I need to convert each struct data into byte array, instead of going through Marshaling, and write to the file, correct? In this case, how do I make sure the next data struct be initialized in the contiguous memory? What do I need to do to declare the MyData struct in the right way? The uCode field in C was a WORD type to store a two-character code and I changed it to a two byte array in C#. Hope this is okay. I have done this project correctly in C but ran into trouble with C#. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: There is no memory. You're writing to a file. To write the header, write an `int`, then write another `int`. To write one of those structs, write a `char`, then another `char` (since apparently `uCode` is two characters disguised as a `WORD`), then a `char[10]`, and so on. You can use `BinaryWriter` for this (thanks Peter, forgot about it). Make sure to set the encoding to whatever single-byte encoding the C code is using (possibly Windows-1252, but who can tell) and mind the padding the C compiler may have added to the fields. You really want to take a look at the bytes that make up a file.

Comment: @@JeroenMostert. I added two methods in the main text. Have you seen them? Data items do not come and populated in sequence so I have to identify them by hash keys and populate the corresponding data fields before writing to the file. That's the reason I cannot write each val as it comes. By the way, I am using BinaryWriter for this purpose. I have followed the same process used in C. Please see the main text in which I will add part of the C code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The endianness seems to be fine. After some changes and testing with the help of Jeroen and others, I am able to make it work. The problem was due to the Block.copy method. I change it to Array.copy as follows:

```
 private byte[] DataToByteArray(MyData data)
{
    int len = 0;
    var size = Marshal.SizeOf(data.GetType());
    var barray = new byte[size];
    data.uCode.CopyTo(barray, 0);
    len += data.uCode.Length;
    data.uLabel.CopyTo(barray, len);
    len += data.uLabel.Length;
    BitConverter.GetBytes(0).CopyTo(barray, len);
    len += data.uData.Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.uData.Length; i++)
       Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(data.uData[i]), 0, barray, len+i * 4, 4);

    return barray;
}
```

Comment: BitConverter.GetBytes(0).CopyTo(barray, len); should be BitConverter.GetBytes(data.uDate).CopyTo(barray, len);

Comment: C# doesn't have Single instead of float.... you posted mistakes...